# Instantly call a phone number with javascript code

Tags: javascript, web

I want to instantly call a phone number using javascript code. So far i have used window.open('tel: '), but the user still has to press the call button. Is there a way to bypass this security mesure, and as soon as the user presses the button, the call is made, without the need to confirm it?

Comment: No, there is not. If any website could call any phone number, hackers would be running up premium-rate phone bills left, right and centre with bits of hidden script. It'd be a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

No. Security measures are security measures. If you want probably *illegal* code, this is not the place to look. As ADyson said, this would be probably the world's biggest security flaw. If this even happened accidentally, this would be a major problem that would cost people millions to billions of dollars. (No research to back this up, but would definitely be a huge cost)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have like facetime or something else that opens these types of links, this works like a charm for me without having to press any window buttons. (DISCLAIMER: This assumes that you have already setup phone numbers to auto open an application on your computer.)

```
<table>
  <tr onclick="window.open('tel:18007776541');">
    <td>Phone: 1-800-777-6541</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Security measures still work on Mac Safari and Mac Chrome. This probably includes iPhone and Android, so this would not work on any iPhones or Android phones.

Comment: Well you probably don't have Facetime setup correctly, for me it opens up inside of my Facetime app. I do have chrome and have previously set it up to any phone numbers I click on will auto open in Facetime. So yeah there is a way to place a call by the click of a button.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. OP wants to override for anyone, not just himself. Plus, you literally just copied the code he gave you and said it was an answer. You also can't blame it on someone not having it set up "correctly," because that isn't even true. If I pull a brand new iPhone off the shelf and run your code, it won't run it. New devices are set up correctly, and if you have a different set up that you think is "correct," then you should have included it in your answer.

Comment: Ok I was just providing a solution that works for me on my computer - so I updated my answer to include that you will need to have that integration already setup in order for this solution to work. :)

Comment: It would be better to tell OP how you changed the setting to enable this. He already has the code.

Comment: OP needs to override. Just be the sure that you are answering true point.